# Prompting multiple values on one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

I need to create a program that fulfills the following.

"Your program should prompt a user for the same input values as in the lab, but rather than having the user enter one value on each line, one line will require multiple values. Each item that follows corresponds to a single line of input:"

```
T1 = input('Test One Score(0-100): ')
T2 = input('Test Two Score(0-100): ')
F1 = input('Final Test Score(0-100): ')
HW = input('Homework Score(0-100): ')
IC = input('Quiz Score(0-100): ')
LAB = input('Lab Score(0-100): ')
BP = input('Bonus Points(0-3): ')

print('Overall Score: ',((float(T1)+float(T2))*.19) + (float(F1) * 0.22) + (float(HW) * 0.18) + (float(IC) * 0.08) + (float(LAB) * 0.14)+(float(BP)))

print("Overall Score Without BP's: ",((float(T1)+float(T2))*.19) + (float(F1) * 0.22) + (float(HW) * 0.18) + (float(IC) * 0.08) + (float(LAB) * 0.14))
```

Formula being used "0.19 (t1 + t2) + 0.22t3 + 0.18hw + 0.08quiz + 0.14lab"

This is what was done the first time but I don't know how to make it so that all the inputs are prompted with only one input.

Comment: *Hint*: Do you know how to "split a string"?

Answer (score 0):

```
all = input("Please input your scores from T1,T2 etc Please separate each value by a space: ")
T1, T2, etc = all.split()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can, of course use the `str.split` method to split a string in a list. ie.

```
a = input('Answer, separate by comma')

# User fills in 42,60,1
a = a.split(',')

# Not required, but probably safer
a = [ a.strip() for a in a.split(',') ]
```

You can also use escape characters to move the cursor around, this isn't *exactly* as how I read your assignment, but IMHO your assignment makes little sense, given that you have 7 questions, all with different constraints. I would consider this more user-friendly (you can, of course, also combine the two solutions)

```
b = input('Question 1: ')

# Move cursor up
print('\x1b[1A', end='')

# Clear line, note this can be combined in 1 print()
print('\x1b[2K', end='')

c = input('Question 2: ')
```

In addition, converting to `int` or `float`, is probably something you want to try/catch, and print a friendly warning:

```
>>> int('42')
42
>>> int('a42')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a42'
```

Note: This answer uses Python 3, it appears you're also using Python 3. Python 2 has a slightly different answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
questions = '''Test One Score(0-100):
Test Two Score(0-100):
Final Test Score(0-100):
Homework Score(0-100):
Quiz Score(0-100):
Lab Score(0-100):
Bonus Points(0-3):'''


T1, T2, F1, HW, IC, LAB, BP = map( input, questions.split('\n'))
```